# Workaround for stop required by python slice()

Tags: python, slice

The python documentation for [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) notes that a stop parameter is always required.

This is good for digging around in data where instead of `x[100000:200000]`, I can instead do something like...

```
sl=slice(100000,200000)
func(x[sl])
func(y[sl])
func(z[sl])
```

But then how would I go about defining something generic for when I want to slice to the end?

```
x[100000:]
```

Comment: That link is not the Python documentation.  The [correct documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) lists two different call signatures. It looks like you want `slice(100000, None)`.

Comment: OK @wim updated to the official, but the question is precisely the same

Comment: @learnvst And the answer in the comment remains the same. Use `None`.

Comment: @wim missed that bit due to word wrapping. Whoops. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place `None` as second parameter: `slice(100000, None)`

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(slice_result):
    # Your function implementation here
    print(slice_result)

# Assuming x is defined somewhere in your code
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

# Define the slice
start_index = 3
end_index = None
sl = slice(start_index, end_index)

# Call the function with the sliced result
func(x[sl])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).